# How can I do to make the output show

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, printing, primes

The question is "ask the user to enter 2 positive integers, print all prime numbers
between these two positive integers, every 5 prime in a row, and print the total."

I didn't see any output of my code. Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM0l0.png)

Comment: The error tells you to indent your code properly if any.

Comment: Your second if statement should be unindented one level. As it is now it will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

`end` in `print()` will help you to define characters after printing.

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

A = int(input("Please enter the lower number: "))
B = int(input("Please eneter the highrt number: "))
#Validate numbers here, both of them should be positive and A<B
total = 0
x = 0
for num in range(A, B+1):
    if isPrime(num):
        print (num, end = " ")
        x += 1
        total += 1
        if x%5 == 0:
            print (end = "\n")
print ()
print (f"Here is the total number of primes: {total}")
```

If it didn't help you ask me for more details.

Comment: Hi, thank you for giving me advice. I tried it just now but the output is  the total from A to B. I want to know how can change it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, because I didn't implement ```isPrime()``` function, it just returns True for all numbers. As I mentioned in comments prime detection number should be implemented in this function. If input number is detected prime then True is returned otherwise False is return, just for True number is printed in console.

Comment: Check ```isPrime()```. It detects prime numbers now.

Comment: It would be great,  if the answer was helpful, up-vote it. @莊璧如